# What is the relationship between a javascript UI library and framework?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, semantic-ui, web-frameworks

I want to know what the relation is between an UI library in javascript and a framework in javascript. Put in more concrete terms/example:

*What is the difference between ReactJS and Semantic UI?*

*How do they work together (if at all)?*

I know semantic UI has a page dedicated to how they work together with React, Meteor and Angular but I do not see the point because to me, it seems like they fullfil the same function.
To be clear: ReactJS and Semantic UI are examples. **I do not seek an in depth comparison between the two but their relation.**

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Framework vs Library is like choosing between buying an off-the-shelf computer and building your own with off-the-shelf parts.

Comment: That is not really what I mean. I mean specifically in javascript (front-end web development). Because they mention eachother, what is the point of using the two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Semantic UI is a library, because it contains a set of user interface (UI) components, which can be used by any framework. These components can be buttons, tables, containers, dividers, etc.

Framework (in this particular case - React) helps you to wire your components together. It contains a set of functions that allow you to connect these pieces in a coherent manner.

- You can build your own components and use react to wire them.
- You can use semantic ui components and wire them using plain HTML and JS.
- You can also use both semantic ui (for components) and react (for wiring).